# is there any way to import the std::find find_if ,etc in Cython?

Tags: c++, vector, cython

Is it possible to import the std::find, in the `libcpp.algorithm` I only find very limited amount of functions there. Now I have to loop through the vector and compare.

Comment: What do you mean _import_? Isn't it sufficient to `#include <algorithm>`?

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: @user0042 Cython exposes some of the C++ standard library to a Python-like language, which provides a way of interfacing C++ and Python. It doesn't look to expose `<algorithm>` particularly completely though, hence the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to follow the scheme used to wrap the other functions in [`libcpp.algorithm`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libcpp/algorithm.pxd):

```
cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":
    Iter find_if[Iter, Func](Iter first, Iter last, Func pred)

from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp cimport bool

cdef bool findtwo(int a):
    if a==2:
        return True


def test():
    cdef vector[int] v = [1,2,3,4,2]
    cdef vector[int].iterator found = find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), findtwo)
    if found != v.end():
        print("Found")
```

You'll find the big limitation is on what you can pass as the predicate function: it has to be a `cdef` function, which means no Python closures, no callable Python objects, etc.. Also be aware than any Python object you return will be interpreted as `true` (i.e. not a `nullptr`) so be sure to return a C++ bool as I have shown.